# Using squashfs for really large root file system images

Tags: linux, squashfs

On boot, in Linux, I'd like to mount my operating system using squashfs (with rw tmpfs overlay).

These images will be used for my normal PC usage, including development and entertainment. I can see these images getting really large.

When I mount squashfs, does it load the entire thing into RAM? Or, does it only load what it needs to decompress into RAM? What if my RAM starts to empty, will previously decompressed files (that aren't being used anymore) by removed from RAM?